# Java split String "[one][two][three]" into array without square brackets

Tags: java, regex

What is the easiest way in Java to split a String of the format "[one][two][three]" into an array without the brackets, for example {"one", "two", "three"} ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: you could simply replace the first `[` and last `]` and split on `][` afterwards.

Comment: But OP should have tried first before posting his homework ... PS : more like a `substring` call followed by a split ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String str="[one][two][three]";
        String delimiter="\\s+|]\\s*|\\[\\s*";
        String [] arr=str.split(delimiter);
        for(String a:arr)
            System.out.print(a);

    }
}
```

Split the string using Delimiters and run the code.
First Split then store it in array
then print array values one by one.

Answer (score 3):

First replace first "[" and last "]".
If you want array you can split using "][".
**arr** is an array. And **string** is to get string.
You can try both.

```
String s = "[one][two][three]";
String arr[] = s.substring(1, s.length()-1).split("\\]\\[");
String string = "{"+s.substring(1, s.length()-1).replace("][", ",")+"}";
```

Answer (score 2):

A version of Kevin's suggestion:

```js
document.write('[one][two][three]'.slice(1,-1).split(']['));
```

Comment: That is Javascript for a Java question ;)

Comment: Keep it, this is the correct algorithm, OP would need to work a bit like this ;)

Comment: @AxelH Oopps. "Misread" the tags :) (did I read them at all? ;)